# Proofs of mathematical optimization theorems

Tags: optimization

How to show that if *x* minimizes *f* over *S* and *x* belongs to *R*, which is a subset of *S*, then *x* also minimizes *f* on *R*
Please help me with this proof.
Thank you.

Comment: If George is the shortest adult in the United States, and George lives in Los Angeles, then George is the shortest adult in Los Angeles.

Comment: @Andre: [...and Los Angeles is in United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_%C3%81ngeles)

Comment: @Ilya: As opposed to [Los Angeles, Mexico](http://g.co/maps/tdnq8).

Comment: @Jackson I am intrigued as to what exactly do you find troubling in this question. Are you having trouble understanding the question? or Are you having trouble understanding some of the terms involved?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a set, and let $x\in S$. Suppose that $x$ minimizes $f(x)$ over $S$. That means that $f(x)\le f(s)$ for all $s\in S$.

Suppose now that $R \subseteq S$. Then certainly $f(x)\le f(r)$ for all $r\in R$, because every $r\in R$ is also in $S$. So if $x\in R$, then $x$ minimizes $f$ over $R$.

The several mathematical symbols in the above argument tend to hide the simplicity of the logic. If Xavier ("$x$") is the shortest person in the United States ($S$), then Xavier is the shortest person in Rochester, NY ($R$).